# Document inclusion by checking existence of command

Tags: errors, input

I am trying to exploit `\ifdefined` to write a document with multiple files. My idea is the following: I define `\ifNotEmbedded` as `\let\ifNotEmbedded\iffalse` in the main document and wrap the preamble of each included file in a checking `\ifNotEmbedded`.

For example, the main file:

```
% main.tex
\let\ifNotEmbedded\iffalse
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\input{introduction.tex}
\end{document}
```

and the included file:

```
%introduction.tex
\ifdefined\ifNotEmbedded
\else
    \let\ifNotEmbedded\iftrue
\fi

\ifNotEmbedded
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\fi
     The content of the introduction goes here.
\ifNotEmbedded
\end{document}
\fi
```

By doing this, I can write the content of `introduction.tex` and test it like a standalone document without having to compile the bigger `main.tex` over and over again and when everything is ready, I can just compile `main.tex` to get the complete article.

The issue I am getting is that: It works perfectly if I compile `introduction.tex` by itself but when I compile `main.tex`, the inclusion doesn't work: I get the following error

**! Incomplete \ifdefined; all text was ignored after line 3.**

How can I make this idea work?

Comment: I can't compile `introduction.tex` ...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Sorry, LaTeX doesn't seem to like empty document. I remove the comment and it should work.

Comment: No, the error was `\if\ifdefined... `in your `introduction.tex`, but it compiles now; `main.tex` not yet... however

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I already fixed that mistake `\if\ifdefined` in some earlier edit.

Comment: I thought I had a solution, but it was none, detected too late .... and David Carlisle commented in the same second ...

Comment: the reason it fails is the usual faq about tex conditionals, if the initial test is true the the `\else` clause is skipped _but matching if..fi_ .  As tex is skipping it does not see `\let`  but it does see `\ifNotEmbedded` and `\iftrue` so it needs to see, and skip over two `\fi` before seeing a `\fi` that ends the test.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  Thanks for the explanation. Indded, adding two additional `\fi` allows me to compile `main.tex` but of course breaks `introduction.tex`. It seems extremely weird to me that the entire `\else .. \fi` is not skipped.

Comment: @AnHoa  the skipping is designed so that you can use `\ifx\a\b  zzz \else  \iffoo  xxxx \fi    \fi`  so it needs to skip to a _matching_ `\fi`   that means you can not do `\ifx\a\b  zzz \else  \iffoo  xxxx    \fi`  and skip over an unmatched `\iffoo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your main file is

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\input{intro}
\end{document}
```

then `intro.tex` could be

```
\makeatletter
\ifx\documentclass\@twoclasseserror
  \typeout{skipping preamble}
  \long\def\zzbegin#1\begin#2{}
  \long\def\zzend#1#2{}
\else
  \typeout{using preamble}
  \let\zzbegin\relax
  \let\zzend\relax
\fi
\makeatother

\zzbegin
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

% The content of the introduction goes here
Foo stuff

\zzend
\end{document}
```

Alternatively of course you could use the standard `\include` mechanism which would have the advantage that you can process individual sections even if they have `\ref` to items in other sections.

Answer (score 0):

I am replicating @DavidCarlisle explanation in the comment and give a fix to the original problem. @DavidCarlisle solution should be preferred since it doesn't depend on eTeX (works with Knuth's TeX as well).

The main issue is that conditionals within `\else .. \fi` are also matched to support the consecutive case scenario (`#if ... #elseif ... #elseif ... #endif` in C++ for example). In my code, if `\ifNotEmbedded` is defined (when compiling `main.tex`), the `\else` won't see `\let` but still see the conditionals `\ifNotEmbedded\iftrue` so it expects two matching `\fi\fi`.

Due to fragility of conditionals within conditional, an easy fix to my original code would be to avoid it by defining a meaningless guarding command, say `\let\InMainFile\relax` and then check if it is defined in those included files i.e. the main file

```
%main.tex
\let\InMainFile\relax
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\input{introduction.tex}
\end{document}
```

and the included file

```
%introduction.tex
\unless\ifdefined\InMainFile
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\fi

The content of the introduction goes here.

\unless\ifdefined\InMainFile
\end{document}
\fi
```

If one is familiar with C/C++, this is exactly the same as using `#ifdef`. I wonder why eTeX doesn't provide another primitive `\ifundefined`.